# Doctrine query findBy returns Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LoggableCursor object

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I don't know what's the problem but when I run this code

```
$reposit = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                            ->getManager()
                            ->getRepository('ngNearBundle:Markers');                        
            $l=$reposit->findBy(array('lat'=>'35.691048'));
```

it returns a  Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LoggableCursor object and not the mongodb document !
what should the problem be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findBy()` method return a collection of all matching results. If you want to get only one result, use `findOneBy()` method.

Comment: It doesn't even return a collection of matching documents ! 
it returns a Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LoggableCursor object

Comment: maybe you have to convert this LoggalbeCursor into an array: ```$reposit->findBy(array('lat'=>'> 35.691048'))->toArray()```

Comment: It gives an empty array , but findOney gives the proper object and the proper array when I use toArray()
what is the problem ?

Comment: I don't know why findBy returns an empty array, sorry.

Comment: The problem was with my query I can't use '>' operator , I should use '$gte'  ;)